# get many MAC Address

Tags: android

I need to many MAC address for one Device in Android.
is it possible to get many MAC Address from one device.?
plz help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Chick here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiInfo.html) for documentation mac address of WiFi controller.
[Click here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#getAddress%28%29) for documentation to find mac address of bluetooth adapter.

**Edit1:**
If you need hardware addresses of all the Wifi access points available to you.
You have scan for the networks ([See here for API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#getScanResults%28%29))
Iterate over results to get mac address of each. ([See here for API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/ScanResult.html))

code will look like

```
List<ScanResult> scanResults= wfManager.getScanResults();
for (ScanResult scanR: scanResults){
 System.out.println(scanR.BSSID);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by many?. Each net controller will have only one mac address (hardware address). I think androids will have many controllers.

Comment: You need addresses of the wifi access points or addresses of controller on device?.

Comment: i need MAC address of available Wifi access point not a device.

Comment: List<WifiConfiguration> list= wfManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
System.out.println("Wifi.."+list.toString));                                         but it return

Comment: Wifi..[ID: 0 SSID: "SPiDiGO" BSSID: null PRIO: 4
KeyMgmt: NONE Protocols: WPA RSN
AuthAlgorithms:
PairwiseCiphers: TKIP CCMP
GroupCiphers: WEP40 WEP104 TKIP CCMP
PSK: 
eap: 
phase2: 
identity: 
anonymous_identity: 
password: 
client_cert: 
private_key: 
ca_cert: ]

Comment: List<ScanResult> scanResults= wfManager.getScanResults();for (ScanResult scanR: scanResults){System.out.println(scanR.BSSID);}

Comment: this is a result of sysout now how i can get MAC address from Wifi..[ID: 0 SSID: "SPiDiGO" BSSID: null PRIO: 4 KeyMgmt: NONE Protocols: WPA RSN AuthAlgorithms: PairwiseCiphers: TKIP CCMP GroupCiphers: WEP40 WEP104 TKIP CCMP PSK: eap: phase2: identity: anonymous_identity: password: client_cert: private_key: ca_cert: ]